# VBA FormatCondition to skip the first row

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight values by applying different conditional formats for each column. However, I cannot find an efficient way to skip the entire first row because it is essentially the title row and no highlights should be applied. Following is the code I have for some columns:

```
'highlight first row white
With y.Sheets(Sh).Range("Y1:Y1").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT(ISBLANK(Y1))")
.Interior.Color = rgbWhite

With y.Sheets(Sh).Range("Y:Y").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="Z")
   .Interior.Color = rgbWhite
    End With
With y.Sheets(Sh).Range("Y:Y").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="NA")
   .Interior.Color = rgbWhite
    End With
With y.Sheets(Sh).Range("Y:Y").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="=" & imput)
   .Interior.Color = rgbOrange
    End With

   End With

'highlight first row white
With y.Sheets(Sh).Range("Z1:Z1").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT(ISBLANK(Z1))")
.Interior.Color = rgbWhite
   End With

With y.Sheets(Sh).Range("Z:Z").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="Z")
   .Interior.Color = rgbWhite
    End With
With y.Sheets(Sh).Range("Z:Z").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="NA")
   .Interior.Color = rgbWhite
    End With
With y.Sheets(Sh).Range("Z:Z").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="=" & imput)
   .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) 'Orange
    End With
```

I pretty much have to add first `with` statement, color first row white, to every column in order to overwrite the later formats. Is there a more efficient way to just keep the first row unfilled?

Comment: Set up your last row as a variable and use `Range("A2:A" & LastRow)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to color the other cells white, and you can combine Columns Y and Z together; Something like this...

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With y.Sheets(Sh).Range("Y2:Z" & LastRow).FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & imput)
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) 'Orange
End With
```

Comment: this only highlights the first row orange. All cell in the column are white instead of the conditioned orange...

Answer (score 1):

With this code it will be easier to define and setup all CF rules you need (for all columns). It applies all rules starting from the 2nd row (bellow header) down to the last used row, so Headers are not affected

To remove all current rules from the sheet and start clean, uncomment this line

- **`ws.Columns.FormatConditions.Delete`**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CFRules()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, minVal As String, lr As Long
    Dim rngCol1Rows As Range, rngCol2Rows As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    minVal = 3  '(imput)

    'ws.Columns.FormatConditions.Delete  'If uncommented, this will remove all CF rules!

    Set rngCol1Rows = ws.Range("Y2:Y" & lr) 'Col Y, except Header (Start Range at Row 2)
    Set rngCol2Rows = ws.Range("Z2:Z" & lr) 'Col Z, except Header

    SetCFRule rngCol1Rows, "=AND(Y2>=" & minVal & ", ISNUMBER(Y2))", rgbOrange
    SetCFRule rngCol2Rows, "=AND(Z2>=" & minVal & ", ISNUMBER(Z2))", RGB(255, 153, 0)

    SetCFRule rngCol1Rows, "=OR(Y2=""Z"", Y2=""NA"")", vbWhite
    SetCFRule rngCol2Rows, "=OR(Z2=""Z"", Z2=""NA"")", vbWhite
End Sub

Private Sub SetCFRule(ByRef cfRng As Range, cfFormula As String, ByVal cfColor As Long)
    With cfRng
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=cfFormula
        .FormatConditions(cfRng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            .Interior.Color = cfColor
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```